# SQL Query for Distinct Result by Most Recent Date

Tags: sql

Dearest Professionals,

I'm in the need to get a few lists of distinct Client #'s by a few date ranges, and I'm not 100% certain how to go about it.

**List 1:**
I need distinct(ClientNum) with the most recent EditDate being 5 years old as of today and older.

**List 2:**
I need distinct(ClientNum) with most recent EditDate between 4 years old today and 5 years old today.

**List 3:**
I need distinct(ClientNum) with most recent EditDate between 3 years old today and 4 years old today.

Now, I have the following, and I get results, I just don't know if I'm getting what I think I should be getting.

**List 1 Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ClientNum)
FROM Table
WHERE EditDate < DATEADD(year,-5,GETDATE())
```

**List 2 Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ClientNum)
FROM Table
WHERE EditDate BETWEEN DATEADD(year,-5,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(year,-4,GETDATE())
```

**List 2 Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ClientNum)
FROM Table
WHERE EditDate BETWEEN DATEADD(year,-4,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(year,-3,GETDATE())
```

Is this the correct way to go about this?  Or am I missing something?

Please advise.

-Nick

Comment: DISTINCT is NOT a function. It works on all columns selected. (column) is nothing but column... Check out GROUP BY, combined with the aggregate function MAX.

Comment: You could select max(editDate), min(EditDate) with the same WHERE clause to make sure. ... and skip the () around DISTINCT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List 1

```
SELECT ClientNum, max(EditDate) as maxEditDate 
FROM Table
GROUP BY ClientNum
HAVING maxEditDate < DATEADD(year,-5,GETDATE());
```

List 2

```
SELECT ClientNum, max(EditDate) as maxEditDate 
FROM Table
GROUP BY ClientNum
HAVING maxEditDate BETWEEN DATEADD(year,-5,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(year,-4,GETDATE());
```

List 3

```
SELECT ClientNum, max(EditDate) as maxEditDate 
FROM Table
GROUP BY ClientNum
HAVING maxEditDate BETWEEN DATEADD(year,-4,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(year,-3,GETDATE());
```

Comment: won't work.  You can't use an alias in the WHERE clause.

Comment: This worked for me.  Thank you, to @Gabriel and everyone else.